# ¿Como puedo librarme de este UNION?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mariadb

La verdad es que desde hace tiempo que en un sistema que tengo existen estas tres tablas que se utilizan para guardar liquidaciones:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Por peticion del usuario, estas tablas deben estar duplicadas en su version final y su version temporal, por lo cual tambien existen las siguientes tablas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El comportamiento es el siguiente: ellos trabajan y las liquidaciones temporales que vayan generando eclipsan a las finales, a la hora de guardar, estas reemplazaran a las que eclipsen y si no se guardan simplemente se descartaran. Para lo siguiente existen estas vistas:

Liquidaciones_temporales:

```
  SELECT 
        dl.id_detalle_liquidacion AS id_detalle_liquidacion,
        c.cod AS cod_concepto,
        c.columna AS columna,
        c.descripcion AS concepto,
        c.no_remunerativo AS no_remunerativo,
        c.no_imponible_9 AS no_imponible_9,
        dl.valor AS valor,
        dl.cantidad AS cantidad,
        dl.comentario AS comentario,
        li.id_liquidacion AS id_liquidacion,
        li.id_empleado AS id_empleado,
        pl.id_periodo_liquidado AS id_periodo_liquidado,
        pl.id_empresa AS id_empresa,
        pl.quincena AS quincena,
        pl.anio AS anio,
        pl.mes AS mes,
        pl.id_sobre AS id_sobre
    FROM
        (((Periodos_liquidados pl
        JOIN Liquidaciones li)
        JOIN Detalles_liquidacion dl)
        JOIN Conceptos c)
    WHERE
        ((pl.id_periodo_liquidado = li.id_periodo_liquidado)
            AND (li.id_liquidacion = dl.id_liquidacion)
            AND (c.id_concepto = dl.id_concepto))
```

Otra vista igual pero con las tablas de liquidaciones guardadas llamada Liquidaciones_guardadas.

Liquidaciones_visibles, que muestra las liquidaciones guardadas no eclipsadas y las temporales:

```
SELECT 
        Liquidaciones_temporales.id_detalle_liquidacion AS id_detalle_liquidacion,
        Liquidaciones_temporales.cod_concepto AS cod_concepto,
        Liquidaciones_temporales.columna AS columna,
        Liquidaciones_temporales.concepto AS concepto,
        Liquidaciones_temporales.valor AS valor,
        Liquidaciones_temporales.cantidad AS cantidad,
        Liquidaciones_temporales.comentario AS comentario,
        Liquidaciones_temporales.id_liquidacion AS id_liquidacion,
        Liquidaciones_temporales.id_empleado AS id_empleado,
        Liquidaciones_temporales.id_periodo_liquidado AS id_periodo_liquidado,
        Liquidaciones_temporales.id_empresa AS id_empresa,
        Liquidaciones_temporales.quincena AS quincena,
        Liquidaciones_temporales.anio AS anio,
        Liquidaciones_temporales.mes AS mes,
        Liquidaciones_temporales.no_remunerativo AS no_remunerativo,
        Liquidaciones_temporales.no_imponible_9 AS no_imponible_9,
        Liquidaciones_temporales.id_sobre AS id_sobre,
        0 AS guardada
    FROM
        Liquidaciones_temporales 
    UNION ALL SELECT 
        lg.id_detalle_liquidacion AS id_detalle_liquidacion,
        lg.cod_concepto AS cod_concepto,
        lg.columna AS columna,
        lg.concepto AS concepto,
        lg.valor AS valor,
        lg.cantidad AS cantidad,
        lg.comentario AS comentario,
        lg.id_liquidacion AS id_liquidacion,
        lg.id_empleado AS id_empleado,
        lg.id_periodo_liquidado AS id_periodo_liquidado,
        lg.id_empresa AS id_empresa,
        lg.quincena AS quincena,
        lg.anio AS anio,
        lg.mes AS mes,
        lg.no_remunerativo AS no_remunerativo,
        lg.no_imponible_9 AS no_imponible_9,
        lg.id_sobre AS id_sobre,
        1 AS guardada
    FROM
        Liquidaciones_guardadas lg
    WHERE
        (NOT (EXISTS( SELECT 
                1 AS Not_used
            FROM
                Liquidaciones_temporales lt
            WHERE
                ((lg.id_sobre = lt.id_sobre)
                    AND (lg.mes = lt.mes)
                    AND (lg.anio = lt.anio)
                    AND (lg.quincena = lt.quincena)
                    AND (lg.id_empresa = lt.id_empresa)
                    AND (lg.id_empleado = lt.id_empleado)))))
```

Tambien existe una vista mas llamada Liquidaciones_guardadas_visibles que muestra solo las liquidaciones guardadas que no son eclipsadas ( es lo que figura en la segunda parte del UNION de la vista anterior pero en su propia view) que cree para testear.

Ahora, tanto las dos vistas de liquidaciones guardadas y liquidaciones temporales son rapidas, resuelven en los siguientes tiempos:
 - Liquidaciones_temporales 0.0031
 - Liquidaciones_guardadas 0.0029
 - Liquidaciones_guardadas_visibles 0.004
 - Liquidaciones_visibles 3.817
Como pueden ver el tiempo en el que se calcula esta ultima es por mucho superior a las demas, se que esto se debe a que la clausula `UNION` es especialmente pesada porque crea tablas temporales y reconstruye sus indices para generar los resultados de la vista. 
Ahora esto para los usuarios no es gran complciacion, no les molesta esperar 4 segundos para obtener el resultado de una consulta y cuando consulto esto en stored procedures se puede optimizar operando las tablas por separado.
 Sin embargo a mi me da curiosidad saber si es posible resolver esta misma vista sin la utilizacion de un `UNION`, o utilizarlo de alguna manera mas performante.

**Nota**: Se me ocurrio que por ahi desformalizando las tablas y almacenando estas 6 en una sola tabla con un criterio que separe a las guardadas, no guardadas y eclipsadas se podria optimizar pero el interrogante que tengo es manteniendo esta estructura.

Comment: intestastes cambiar el union con un left join y colocara en el on los parametros del where? deberia ser mas rapido

Comment: Si, pero entonces tendria el problema de que tendria todos los datos pero una tabla el doble de ancha y la mitad de alta ¿No? Digo, parte del sentido de crear estas vistas es que todas tengan los mismos campos

Comment: otra opcion es crear una tabla temporal con los campos insertar las dos consultas y luego el select, hice esto y me fue muy bien

Comment: Hice una prueba simple con una tabla temporal, voy a saltear la lista de campos para acortar el comentario, pero basicamente ejecute estas dos sentencias:
`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_liq SELECT * FROM Liquidaciones_temporales;`
`INSERT INTO tmp_liq SELECT * FROM Liquidaciones_guardadas_visibles;`
La primera es rapida, resuelve en 40 milisegundos, la segunda sin embargo tarda 7 segundos y medio

Comment: Disculpa, porque deben estar en 2 estructuras separadas idénticas, en vez de agregar un atributo booleano (como "Temporal") a cada tabla (o solo en la que creas necesaria) de la estructura actualmente utilizada?

Comment: Porque tienen que poder coexistir temporales y no temporales a la vez, tiene que ver conla peticion de los usuarios de que este separado. De todas formas la solucion que @JackNavaRow propuso con un left join creo que me dio una idea de como solucionar. Ademas de que la tabla de liquidaciones guardadas no es 100% identica  ala temporal, esta almacena copias de datos de los conceptos como el numero de codigo que tienen, la descripcion, etc que se congelan cuando se graban. Como dije, se que desnormalizarlo es una solucion pero queria saber de una que no altere la estructura.

Comment: Bueno, basandome en los comentarios que me dejaron y un poco de prueba y error por mi parte di con la solucion de agregar un registro a la tabla temporal y usarlo para pivotear en un left join.<br>En un entorno de desarrollo con unos 151258 registros resulto bien, con unos 0.0075 segundos mientras que en produccion con casi la misma cantidad ( 167197 ) tarda mas de 30 segundos, resultando en un timeout.
https://pastebin.com/BN2C9pAE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final analizando el problema llegue a la conclusion de que si achicaba las tablas a unir entonces la consulta se hacia mas rapidamente, de modo que cree un stored procedure para llenar una tabla temporal, asi:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `crear_tabla_liquidaciones_visibles`(IN id_empresa INT, IN anio INT, IN mes INT, IN quincena INT)
BEGIN

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_liquidaciones_visibles;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_liquidaciones_visibles ENGINE=MEMORY
    SELECT lt.id_detalle_liquidacion AS id_detalle_liquidacion,
           lt.cod_concepto AS cod_concepto,
           lt.columna AS columna,
           lt.concepto AS concepto,
           lt.valor AS valor,
           lt.cantidad AS cantidad,
           lt.comentario AS comentario,
           lt.id_liquidacion AS id_liquidacion,
           lt.id_empleado AS id_empleado,
           lt.id_periodo_liquidado AS id_periodo_liquidado,
           lt.id_empresa AS id_empresa,
           lt.quincena AS quincena,
           lt.anio AS anio,
           lt.mes AS mes,
           lt.no_remunerativo AS no_remunerativo,
           lt.no_imponible_9 AS no_imponible_9,
           lt.id_sobre AS id_sobre,
           0 AS guardada
      FROM Liquidaciones_temporales lt
     WHERE lt.anio = anio
       AND (lt.mes = mes OR mes = -1)
       AND (lt.quincena = quincena OR quincena = -1)
       AND lt.id_empresa = id_empresa;

    INSERT INTO tmp_liquidaciones_visibles
    SELECT lg.id_detalle_liquidacion AS id_detalle_liquidacion,
           lg.cod_concepto AS cod_concepto,
           lg.columna AS columna,
           lg.concepto AS concepto,
           lg.valor AS valor,
           lg.cantidad AS cantidad,
           lg.comentario AS comentario,
           lg.id_liquidacion AS id_liquidacion,
           lg.id_empleado AS id_empleado,
           lg.id_periodo_liquidado AS id_periodo_liquidado,
           lg.id_empresa AS id_empresa,
           lg.quincena AS quincena,
           lg.anio AS anio,
           lg.mes AS mes,
           lg.no_remunerativo AS no_remunerativo,
           lg.no_imponible_9 AS no_imponible_9,
           lg.id_sobre AS id_sobre,
           1 AS guardada
      FROM Liquidaciones_guardadas lg
     WHERE lg.anio = anio
       AND (lg.mes = mes OR mes = -1)
       AND (lg.quincena = quincena OR quincena= -1)
       AND lg.id_empresa = id_empresa
       AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1
                         FROM Liquidaciones_temporales lt2
                        WHERE lt2.anio= anio
                          AND (lt2.mes= mes OR mes = -1)
                          AND (lt2.quincena= quincena OR quincena = -1)
                          AND lt2.id_empresa= id_empresa
                          AND lt2.id_sobre = lg.id_sobre
                          AND lt2.mes = lg.mes
                          AND lt2.anio = lg.anio
                          AND lt2.quincena = lg.quincena
                          AND lt2.id_empresa = lg.id_empresa
                          AND lt2.id_empleado = lg.id_empleado);
END
```

El tema esta en que estan parametrizados los wheres a las vistas, de modo que solo se opera con los conjuntos luego de ser filtrados, lo cual es mucho mas rapido que unir las tablas y luego filtrarlos.
En conclusion: creo que la mejor manera de solucionarlo seria si se pudieran parametrizar las vistas, pero mysql no lo permite mas alla de con algun workaround como se ve en [este link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281890/can-i-create-view-with-parameter-in-mysql).